# sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy - deploying SOAP webservices on weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, weblogic

I have a simple webservices apps that I'm deploying to weblogic 10.3.6. I have some dependent jar files for the project. I have a jar file for an app that I'm working with (oimclient.jar). When I package that jar file with the war file, it throws the following error:

```
Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1382734445347' for task '19'. Error is: 'weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'SampleApp.war''
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'SampleApp.war'
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:395)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
  at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
  Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check in SampleApp's pom if there are `provided` dependencies that are not actually in you container.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the version of the oimclient jar that you are using(copied from $OIM_HOME/server/client) has some problems with weblogic deployment.You need to copy oimclient jar file from a different location as below-

1. Go to $OIM_HOME/server/apps
2. Copy spml-xsd.ear file to your local machine
3. Extract the file using unzip utility
4. Use the oimclient jar that is under spml-xsd\APP-INF\lib

This will solve your problem.